# What is the meaning of the term 'context' in Akka/Spray

Tags: scala, akka, spray, akka-http

I am new to Akka/Spray and Scala. I see from akka docs that there is HttpRequest which is the Http Request class and there is also the RequestContext which according to akka docs

> encapsulates the context of an HttpRequest as it flows through a
>   akka-http Route structure.

May I know what is the meaning of the term 'context' here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at how akka-http `Route` type is defined:

```
type Route = scala.Function1[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext, scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]]
```

As we can see Route essentially is a function transforming `RequestContext` into `Future[RouteResult]`, so you can think of `RequestContext` as a portion of data representing `HttpRequest` and some additional information.

In fact, taking a deeper look into `akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext` we will find a trait:

```
trait RequestContext {
  val request: HttpRequest
  val unmatchedPath: Uri.Path
  implicit def executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor
  implicit def materializer: Materializer
  def log: LoggingAdapter
  def settings: RoutingSettings
  def parserSettings: ParserSettings
  def reconfigure(
    executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = executionContext,
    materializer:     Materializer             = materializer,
    log:              LoggingAdapter           = log,
    settings:         RoutingSettings          = settings): RequestContext
  // ...
}
```

(comments removed from code)

So essentially context gives you some metadata about `HttpRequest`.